# Stay vs be in the given sentences

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Do we say, "How much longer are you going to **stay** online?", or do we say "How much longer are you going **be** online."

Or, could we just use either?

Answer (score 1):

You may use either, although **be** is the more common usage in my experience in the US. Most people I know normally leave their devices connected to the internet even when not actively using that connection, so the device may **stay** online all day, even though we are not actively "doing anything" online. I would infer that **be online** is describing an individual actively using that connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

In this example they are both fine, but the meanings are slightly different, which may matter if the context is different.  **Stay** emphasizes that you were online already, whereas **be** only refers to whether you are online at the moment of interest (indicated by context).  The rest of the sentence fills in the difference in this example so they are interchangeable here.

Where it might matter:   "Are you going to stay online?"  vs.  "Are you going to be online?"

The difference here could be very important.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between **be** and **stay**.

If you're in the lavatory, and someone needs to get in, these two questions would have somewhat different implications:

> How long are you going to be in there?
>
> How long are you going to stay in there?

All things being equal, the word **stay** has a tinge of impatience to it.

**How long are you going to be online?** suggests that the speaker understands you to be doing some task that must be completed. It doesn't have to be an important task, just something that can be completed.

**How long are you going to stay online?** suggests the speaker believes you are free to quit whenever you want; no particular task is keeping you there.